# Cannot get FullCalendar to populate with my event array

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have researched and I cannot get my solution to work.  I have created my rest service to provide the event data as needed...

```
[
  {"id":"cb2eb05b-7a24-431c-8948-d08fb51f6bab","title":"Happy Birthday Pat!","allDay":false,"start":"2017-12-30T03:00:00","end":"2017-12-31T02:30:00","url":""},
  {"id":"89fdeab5-1f49-4416-b81c-d9d9a3c4fbde","title":"RailJam on Westway","allDay":false,"start":"2017-12-31T15:00:00","end":"2017-12-31T19:00:00","url":""},
  {"id":"37afb0e6-e659-46a3-a048-5f13560ebe87","title":"Senior OEC Clinic","allDay":false,"start":"2018-01-07T11:00:00","end":"2018-01-07T19:00:00","url":""},
  {"id":"6d74033c-39ce-4d43-b642-bceed34e2294","title":"Senior OEC Clinic","allDay":false,"start":"2018-01-21T11:00:00","end":"2018-01-21T19:00:00","url":""},
  {"id":"36ca8f3b-6696-49f4-b7b7-a405660358e8","title":"Senior OEC Clinic","allDay":false,"start":"2018-01-28T11:00:00","end":"2018-01-28T19:00:00","url":""},
  {"id":"3b1a86ec-d09a-467d-ad83-43864439db1f","title":"Senior OEC Clinic","allDay":false,"start":"2018-02-03T11:00:00","end":"2018-02-03T19:00:00","url":""}
]
```

I have create my MVC page with the fullcalendar plug in...

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>

<link href="../../FullCalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../FullCalendar/lib/moment.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FullCalendar/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../FullCalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            color: 'blue',
            textColor: 'white',
            events: 'http://localhost:3276/rest/bsp/events/'
        });
    });
</script>

<div id='calendar'></div>
```

But I am still not able to get my events to publish on the calendar.

[Missing Events In FullCalendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgrck.png)

I am sure it is a simple mistake that I have missed...can anyone shed some light?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/152/ shows that your events work when the URL is replaced by a static list containing your example JSON. So probably your ajax call to `http://localhost:3276/rest/bsp/events/` is at fault. If you haven't already done so, you need to debug it using your browser's developer tools and provide some relevant information about it. Is the request successful (check the Network tab)? Does it return exactly the data in your sample as the response (and nothing else)? Are there any errors in the browser's Console tab?

Answer (score 0):

Success. My results were wrapped in HTML so not pure JSON. Corrected by returning a stream returned pure JSON string, not an HTML representation of the string.